# Filter itens without direct relation in Django Rest Framework API

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement some filters in my API endpoint for a property management company. I want to filter reservations in a range of check-in dates and properties. I have three models called Reservation, Listing and Property.

The reservation has a Foreign Key to Listing, which has a Foreign Key to Property. I want to filter a reservation with a specific Property, but they don't have a direct relation, the Listing is in the middle.

```
models.py

from django.db import models
from .helpers import support_models

class Reservation(models.Model):
  code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  check_in_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
  check_out_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.code

class Listing(models.Model):
   code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   def __str__(self):
    return self.code

class Property(support_models.Address):
  code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.code
```

I have many more itens in the models, but I'm showing you only what I need.

My views are looking like this at the moment:

```
views.py

from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions, filters
from sapron import models, serializers

class ReservationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Reservation.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ReservationSerializer
    filterset_fields = {
        'check_in_date': ['gte', 'lte'],
        'listing': ['exact'],
    }
```

The date range filter is working fine, but I want 'property' instead of 'listing' in the second filter field. The 'listing' one works, but when I type 'property' I get and error "Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: property".

Also, I want to be able to filter more than one property.

Comment: Hi Mau! I suggest writing your own filterset_class instead of using the shortcut `filterset_fields`. In general you are allowed to use djangos lookup syntax, so you can do things like `listing__property`. Does this help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with the django-filter package can be unnecessarily verbose and limited. Yves' comment highlights what you can do if you want to stick with this package. However, I have personally found this solution below to be far more flexible, easy to implement, and overall useful:

**views.py**

```py
def BaseAPIView(...):

    ''' base view for other views to inherit '''

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = self.queryset

        # get filter request from client:
        filter_string = self.request.query_params.get('filter')

        # apply filters if they are passed in:
        if filters: 
            filter_dictionary = json.loads(filter_string)
            queryset = queryset.filter(**filter_dictionary)

        return queryset
```

The request url will now look like, for example: `my_website.com/api/products?filters={"name":"book"}`

Or more precisely: `my_website.com/api/products?filters=%7B%22name%22:%22book%22%7D`

Which can be built like:

**script.js**

```js
// using ajax as an example:
var filter = JSON.stringify({
  "name" : "book"
});

$.ajax({
   "url" : "my_website.com/api/products?filter=" + filters,
   "type" : "GET",
   ...
});
```

**Some advantages:**

- no need to specify which fields can be filtered on each view class
- write it once, use it everywhere
- front end filtering looks exactly like django filtering
- can do the same with `exclude`

**Some disadvantages:**

- potential security risks if you want some fields to be non-filterable
- less intuitive front-end code to query a table

Overall, this approach has been far more useful for me than any packages out there.